# After upgrading to linux kernel 3.9, kde does not start correctly

Tags: debian, kde, linux-kernel, tty

I recently upgrade my debian from kernel 3.2 to 3.9. This leads to a strange problem. After booting to kernel 3.9, it directly goes to tty7 instead of kde login. I can identify that kdm is up and running from ps.

Also, running

```
service kdm restart
```

no error message is present.

Another noticeable thing is that now I cannot switch to "tty7" which ought to be the "tty" for graphic contents.

Is there a direction that I can further investigate this problem and, maybe find a solution?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

2nd aptitude reinstall nvidia-kernel-dkms

3rd reboot

Comment: You could try to extend your answer a bit with a bit more explanation and text.

Comment: Thanks maq. I confirmed that it is the video card driver problem, though I am using the official one from the nvidia website. It seems that the dkms is not correctly configured so that the driver does not migrate to the new kernel.